# System.OutOfMemoryException when merging Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: plugins, json.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, ilmerge

I am creating a plugin to call a webservice. I need to serialize and deserialize the Json object. So, I need Newtonsoft.Json. I am trying to merge the dll from NewtonSoft.Json and my application dll using ILMerge.MSBuild.Task and ILMerge in Visual Studio 2015.

I get the error below:
[image]

I looked for solution in internet but could not find any solution.

Comment: Add **/ndebug:true** help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439721/is-there-a-way-to-merge-pdb-files-with-ilmerge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ILMerge in VisualStudio Use the necessary dlls from NuGet Package Manager Only

I was using the **MSBuild.ILMerge.Task 1.0.5** and latest verson of **Newtonsoft.Json** and getting this type of issue.

I tried with to stable version by downgrade to **Newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.3** and it works well.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ILMerge only to serialize/deserialize JSON I'd recommend to drop it and use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class instead. This change would remove the dependency with Newtonsoft.Json and ILMerge ([not supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2010/11/09/how-to-reference-assemblies-from-plug-ins/)) to end up with a lighter plugin library (which is always good):

```
// Deserialize a JSON stream to a User object.  
public static User ReadToObject(string json)  
{  
    User deserializedUser = new User();  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));  
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedUser.GetType());  
    deserializedUser = ser.ReadObject(ms) as User;  
    ms.Close();  
    return deserializedUser;  
}
```

Full example can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by taking the latest dll from nuget, & just putting it into side folder & reference the dll direct.

Im not sure why nuget messes it up, but after i took nuget out of the picture the the build worked.

I don't like the fact that i cant use nuget for getting updates for this project, but as least it workes.