# Include Newtonsoft Json.NET in project without DLL

Tags: .net, json.net

I am using Json.NET in my C# project and I am currently using "Embedded Resource" for Newtonsoft.Json.dll and my app became detected by some security apps so I can no longer use this way. I do not want to have Newtonsoft.Json.dll next to my EXE file, so I am wondering if there is any way to include Json.NET to my project without using DLL?

Comment: You might try some of the solutions from [Can a .NET windows application be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126611/3744182).  Though see [System.OutOfMemoryException when merging Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53602936/3744182).

Comment: I haven't tried merging DLL with EXE with other apps, but if Embedded DLL from Visual Studio is detected I think it will be the same?

Comment: In [Can a .NET windows application be compressed into a single .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126611/3744182), assemblies are getting merged into a single assembly as if they had been compiled as a single project by Visual Studio, by directly combining their IL code.  See e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge.  What you're doing is embedding an assembly in a resource file then loading it via reflection.  That going to look quite different to an antivirus scan.  But the only way to know for sure is to actually try.

Comment: I have now used ILMerge but new exe is than detected and automatically closed. I guess I will have to change code for serialize and use something else...

Comment: Why not download json.net source code and make it part of your solution? This is the *cleanest* way from an antivirus perspective.

Comment: What is it about Json.Net that is getting flagged by your security programs?

Comment: Using source and make it part of my app would probably solve this problem, but I dont know how to include it, was searching for some tutorial but can’t manage to do it.

Comment: I’m not sure what triggers security program, probably not Json.net but the fact that DLL is embedded.